# netbeans derby, no username-schema created in new database on mac

Tags: macos, netbeans, derby

I'm a beginner so I might be missing something, but when I create a new derby database in netbeans on windows, if I specify username and password, a schema with the same name of the username is created, but when I create database with username in netbeans on mac osx, no schema is created, the database has just the default schemas, app, nullid etc, is this a bug or is there a setting for this behavior? 
both netbeans and derby are newest version.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just misreading the behavior. The behavior on Windows and Mac is identical. Derby implicitly creates a schema named with the username on-the-fly. But you can explicitly reference schemas too, by fully-qualifying table names, etc., by using the CREATE SCHEMA statement, etc. You are probably just not using the username that you think you are, or you are not looking at the same database that you think you, or something like that.

Try making your question more concrete by posting exact scripts of what you're doing, e.g., using the 'ij' tool on both machines, so we can see what you might be doing differently. I routinely use Derby across Windows, Mac, and Linux, and I've always found the username/schemaname handling to be consistent.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help, I did a little more test on my Mac and I found when I use command tool 'ij', the schema named with username is created on the fly, however, if I create the db in Netbeans, by right-clicking Java DB and select 'create database', and I'm sure I entered username and password and confirmed password, but in the created db I can see only the default schemas.
attached is a screenshot, you can see in the highlighted line on the right there is the username 'tom' and the supposed schema 'TOM', but there is no 'TOM' schema on the list below.

Comment: here is the [screenshot](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7185/6804726166_82df0bc49f.jpg)

Comment: What's probably happening is that you're working with two different copies of the same database, and getting yourself confused. If your Derby database URL specifies a relative (not absolute) database name, and if it also includes create=true, then Derby will create a new database relative to the current directory, and the current directory is probably different each time you try this.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I'm sure I'm not working with different copies of the db, I created the db on Mac with exactly the same steps on Windows, and I created the db in NetBeans, I didn't have to add 'create=true', and the directory is relative only to derby database location, which is set only in NetBeans.

Comment: Would you repeat my steps in creating this situation?
1. in NetBeans 7.1 for Mac - Service - Java DB - Create database
2. Enter DB name, user name, password, confirm password - OK
3. connect to newly created DB, is there a schema named with the username?
many thanks!

Comment: sorry, it's netbeans 7.0.1 on mac

Comment: I don't think that just creating the database will create the user's schema. I think you have to either (a) issue the CREATE SCHEMA statement, or (b) create a table, view or some other object which causes the creation of the schema as a side effect: http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#schema_exist

Comment: Thank you Bryan! I tried your side effect approach and it worked, thank you very much for your help!