# Unable to execute statements on Web Logic derby Data Source

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, derby

I am using WebLogic Server to access a database. I have added the database to my WebLogic Server instance via the Admin Console. It's an apache derby DB. I am able to establish a connection in my code, but every time I try to execute a statement I get an exception:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'WEBLOGIC' does not exist
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)

When talking with others, I have heard that maybe my derby version is old, but I just downloaded the latest version (10.14.2.0). I have also noticed that WLS has it's own derby directory (Oracle_Home\wlserver\common\derby), so I tried replacing the lib folder there with the latest version, but that didn't help anything.

The exception occurs in my InsertStudents method when I try to execute my statement. I'm totally lost here.

````````
  public class JNDIPrinter {
  private static String tableName = "student";
  // jdbc Connection
  private static Connection conn = null;
  private static Statement stmt = null;

  public void AddStudents() {
    Context ctx = null;
    try {
      conn = GetConnection();
      List<Student> students;

      students = new ArrayList<Student>(
          Arrays.asList(new Student("first1", "last1", "111-11-1111", "1@1.com", "111 1st st", "user1", "pw1"),
              new Student("first2", "last2", "222-22-2222", "2@2.com", "222 2nd st", "user2", "pw2"),
              new Student("first3", "last3", "333-33-3333", "3@3.com", "333 3rd st", "user3", "pw3")));

      InsertStudents(students);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
      if (ctx != null) {
        try {
          ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
          System.out.println("Failed to close context due to: " + e);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private Connection GetConnection() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    Context ctx = null;
    String url = null;
    System.out.println(url);
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    // This *required* property specifies the factory to be used
    // to create the context.
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");

    if (url != null) {
      // This property specifies the URL of the WebLogic Server that will
      // provide the naming service. Defaults to t3://localhost:7001
      env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    }

    ctx = new InitialContext(env);
    System.out.println("Initial context created");
    DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jhuDataSource");
    System.out.println("Datasource created");
    java.sql.Connection connection = (java.sql.Connection) ds.getConnection();
    return connection;
  }

  private void InsertStudents(List<Student> students) throws SQLException{
    try {
      for (Student student : students) {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("insert into " + tableName + " values ('" 
                                                  + student.first_name + "','" 
                                                  + student.last_name +  "','" 
                                                  + student.ssn +       "','"
                                                  + student.email +     "','" 
                                                  + student.address +   "','" 
                                                  + student.userID +    "','" 
                                                  + student.password +  "')");
        stmt.close();
      }
    } catch (SQLException sqlExcept) {
      sqlExcept.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```````
````````

Comment: As stated in your error message, your datasource configuration is connected to a derby schema named "WEBLOGIC" but this schema does not exist in your configuration. So, create a WEBLOGIC scehame inside your database or update your datasource configuration to use your own schema.

Comment: For more information on how Derby determines the default schema if you do not specify one, try searching StackOverflow for 'Derby default schema', and you'll find useful related questions such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032112/why-derby-does-not-use-property-currentshema-from-my-was-datasource and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313649/derby-and-sql-requests-issue-how-is-the-default-schema-determined and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546556/netbeans-derby-no-username-schema-created-in-new-database-on-mac